# Django-Leaflet show custom layers on a form

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms, leaflet, geodjango

I have two models, one that shows a marker(PointField) and one that generates PolygonFields.

In my views, i can perfectly show all the data on a map.
However, I would like to show the same data when creating a new geometry. Question is, how do I overlay the marker and the polygonField data as a layer in a form.

models

```
class MyPolygon(gis_models.Model):
    geom    = gis_models.PolygonField()
    objects = gis_models.GeoManager()

class MyPoints(gis_models.Model):
    geom    = gis_models.PolygonField()
    objects = gis_models.GeoManager()
```

views

```
class PolygonCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class = PolygonForm
    template_name = 'applications/create_polygon.html'
    success_url = '/applications/polygon'

def view_polygon(request):
    polygons= ReserveAirspace.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'applications/polygons.html',{'polygons':polygons})
```

same applies to the points.

html

```
{{form.geom}}
```

How do i add all the existing polygons and points to the form field above in the template???

Answer (score 0):

You will need to add the geometries to your leaflet map with JavaScript.  You can either return them as geojson from another view or extend your CreateView like this:

```
class PolygonCreateView(CreateView):
    # ....
    def all_polygons(self):
        return MyPolygon.objects.all()
```

and access them from your template using `{{ view.all_polygons }}`.